# Choosing function index or new column index

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database I would like to search for all results for a certain week number.
What is the difference/ which is more efficient:
Using a function index:

```
CREATE INDEX week_number_index ON my_table (EXTRACT (WEEK FROM date));
```

:OR:
Creating a new column with an index storing the week number for each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index expressions like you have in your example are computed on insert. This means that you'd see the same search improvement vs an index on a new column, but without the overhead and mental cost of storing data in a new column.
Your expression index is the way to go.

Sources:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#expression-indexes
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: I agree, but what do you mean by "mental cost"?

Comment: I just mean that as a table has more columns added, it takes a little more brainpower to understand everything that it stores. Especially when this data would be redundant. In other words, keep the schema simple

Comment: @dementis . . . I think it takes much *more* brainpower to remember both column names and functional expressions used for indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The amount of data being presented is less when using an expression index. You have just an index. If you have a column AND an index, then every time you look at the table, you will constantly have to mentally filter out this column that doesn't really contribute to the model; the data is already present on another column. It's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is really in how you want access the data.  In both cases, the overhead of maintaining the index occurs on `insert`/`update`/`delete` operations.  Any overhead for calculating the value is minimal (in this case).

If you want to use:

```
where EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) = :x
```

Then use a functional index.

If you want to use:

```
where date_week = :x
```

then use a column.

More importantly, I think it is bad idea to exclude the year when pulling the week.  I would recommend `date_trunc('week', date)` for either index.